# If 20 engineers and 20 workers can construct a 20 km road in 20 days, how long does it take for 40 engineers and 40 workers to construct a 40 km road?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If 20 engineers and 20 workers can together construct a 20 km road in 20 days. 40 engineers and 40 workers together construct a 40 km road in how many days?

Total work done in 20 days= 20*20=400 units( 20km road in 20 days)
Now in the solution it has been given
for 40 km road 800 man power is required. How to calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

20 engineers and 20 workers make 1 km road/day

40 engineers and 40 workers make 2 km road/day

Since 40 engineers and 40 workers make 2 km road/day they need 20 days.

Answer (score 0):

If 20 engineers and 20 workers can  construct a 20 km road in 20 days then

20 engineers and 20 workers can  construct a 40 km road in 40 days.

Thus,   40 engineers and 40 workers can  construct a 40 km road in 20 days.

Answer (score 0):

Note that twice as many staff will do twice as much work. Therefore, they will take the same. 20 days.